# change percentage from decimal to numerical value

Tags: xml, decimal, percentage

I have a feed that is currently outputting a discount amount as a decimal value, I'm trying to change it so that it is a two digiy figure with no decimals.

Example, it's currently 0.2 but I want as 20 and idea how I can amend this code?

```
/* Calculate order discount percentage */
                Double osub = Double.Parse(OrderSubtotal);
                Double damt = -Double.Parse(DiscAmt);
                DiscAmt = damt.ToString(); // Show discount amount as a  positive number. 

                if ((damt>0.0)&&(osub>0.0))
                {
                    Double dperc = damt / osub;
                    DiscPerc = dperc.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply `damt` by 100. If you don't want `double` precision (meaning, fractional percentage points), then cast/round to an `int` after multiplying by 100.